# crear un <td> fijo que no recorra el json

Tags: javascript

tengo mi codigo:

```
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
 if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
  const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
 posts.currentList.lvl1.forEach(item => {
 document.getElementById("Raid01").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `aqui va la tabla que 
  recorre el .json ); } );

  }
```

me gustaria crear un  td (< td >) antes de recorrer el json; un < td > fijo como cabecera..
me ayudan?

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un sample de la respuesta del request?, por otra parte, considera usar [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) en vez del objeto ajax.

Comment: va creando tablas < td > segun el recorrido del json, me gustaria agregarle un < td > como titulo que no reccorra mi json

Comment: Agregalo antes de llamar a `.forEach`, de esta forma el elemento que agregues quedará antes. Se agregará cuando la petición ajax sea respondida dentro de los parámetros que especificaste en el bloque `if`.